# Filter with a main criterion and sub criterion

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

Consider a table with three columns A, B and C. I want to sort this table using the following two criteria.

1. Main Criterion: Sort the whole table according to column C so that entries in C is increasing. For example, `2009`, `2009`, `2010`, `2010`, etc.
2. Sub Criterion: When the entries in column C are the same, say, `2009`, I want to sort the table so that the entries in column B are decreasing. For example, if there are two `2009` in C, then I want B to have `100` and `99`.

How do I achieve this in Excel, please?

Comment: Did you try going to Data=>Sort and sort the columns they way you want then filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is adapted from *Recorded* code.  Starting with data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
   .SortFields.Clear
   .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C20"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B20"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
   .SetRange Range("A1:C20")
   .Header = xlNo
   .MatchCase = False
   .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
   .SortMethod = xlPinYin
   .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]